# Quarkus Lambda Memory Leakage

Tags: aws-lambda, quarkus, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, quarkus-native

I have created an amazon lambda using Quarkus framework and packaged it using GraalVM native-image. The functionalities is quite simple with basic validations, however I am creating Dynamo DB client and SQS clients.
I have instantiated those clients outside of Quarkus Request Handler and using Http Client Connection  while building the clients as mentioned in this guide: https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-lambda#aws-sdk-v2

In the AWS console, I have set the max memory as 256 mb (This is the requirement). The first invocation takes about 1000ms and uses 74 mb. However for each consecutive invocation of lambda, the memory consumption keeps on increasing and it instantiates all the clients (Dynamo DB and SQS) again and again. Is there a way to keep the memory consumed lower and instantiating these clients once in a while as and when required?